# dictSession.getSchema is not a function (Node.js/MySQL/xdevapi)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have started using xdevapi for Node.js as mysql connector. By following this guide (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/connecting-to-a-single-mysqld-node-setup.html):

```
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

var dictSession = mysqlx.getSession( {
        host: 'localhost', 'port': 33060,
        user: 'root', password: '' } )

var db1 = dictSession.getSchema('test')
```

I got an error:

> dictSession.getSchema is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using synchronous JavaScript syntax that only works in the MySQL Shell (as depicted in the link you point to). Unfortunately, that guide does not seem to include a proper snippet for the Connector/Node.js version where the `getSession()` method is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`, which means you need to attach a proper `then()` handler, in which `dictSession` will eventually be resolved.

```
mysqlx.getSession({ host: 'localhost', 'port': 33060, user: 'root', password: '' })
  .then(function (dictSession) {
    var db1 = dictSession.getSchema('test')
  });
```

or you can use the `async/await` flavour:

```
var dictSession = await mysqlx.getSession({ host: 'localhost', 'port': 33060, user: 'root', password: '' })
var db1 = dictSession.getSchema('test')
```

I'll make sure the guide will include a proper example.

Disclaimer: I'm the X DevAPI Node.js connector lead dev.